# three.js; Cannot read property 'position' of undefined and don't know why

Tags: javascript, properties, three.js, webgl, undefined

I'm gonna make my SUN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! SUNGOD!!! urg---!

..sorry.

It doesn't work as well.

Error message shown on console and it said;

> // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined;

Here is source

```
// Constructing * The Solar *
var shape = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    shape.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32Attribute(6,3));
    // console shows problem is here but I can't find any
    shape.addAttribute('textureOrder', new THREE.Int8Attribute(6,1));


    for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        shape.attribute.position.setXYZ(i, 0, 0, 0);
        shape.attribute.textureOrder.setX(i, i);
    };

var d = new Date();

var mater = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        time: { type: 'f', value: d.getTime() },
        tsun_core: { type: 't', value: loadTexture('./sun_core.png') },
        tsun_innerglow: { type: 't', value: loadTexture('./sun_innerglow.png') },
        tsun_starlight: { type: 't', value: loadTexture('./sun_starlight.png') },
        tsun_outerglow: { type: 't', value: loadTexture('./sun_outerglow.png') },
        tsun_shortjetlight: { type: 't', value: loadTexture('./sun_shortjetlight.png') },
        tsun_longjetlight: { type: 't', value: loadTexture('./sun_longjetlight.png') }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vs-sun').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fs-sun').textContent
});
    mater.depthTest = false;
    mater.vertexColor = true;
    mater.transparent = true;
    mater.blending = THREE.AdditiveBlending;

sun = new THREE.ParticleSystem(shape, mater);
scene.add(sun);
```

My goal is, change gl_FragColor opacity by `uniform time` in fragment shader so my sun(?) to be more dynamic...

My opinion, cause of problem be somewhere above source. Please guide me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `addAttribute` method on a `THREE.BufferGeometry` instance creates properties under the `attributes` property, not `attribute`.

Replaces these lines

```
    shape.attribute.position.setXYZ(i, 0, 0, 0);
    shape.attribute.textureOrder.setX(i, i);
```

With the following lines

```
    shape.attributes.position.setXYZ(i, 0, 0, 0);
    shape.attributes.textureOrder.setX(i, i);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not good at english so your correction very appreciate